# GAE Prevent File Access

Tags: google-app-engine, file-permissions

I have a GAE project I'm about to deploy. Everything is going well except I seemingly can't protect certain files. In particular I've uploaded my .p12 key file to use with APNS. I had it in WEB-INF originally but due to a " java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=111, too big." I've moved the file outside of this directory. The issue I'm having now is that I'm able to download the .p12 file. Working on the local dev server I have the following permissions and therefore blocking access to the file. However, once I push this out to production I'm still able to download the file. What might it be about the GAE production environment that is not enforcing this security constraint? Thank you for any help.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>certificates</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/certificates/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Why would you place a p12 file anywhere near the webapp folder and worry about its security? Put it in resources and get it with the commonly known resource methods.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the documents, you need to have a role specified inside of "auth-constraint", as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication)

So something like

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>certificates</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/certificates/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I tried to do this. But yet it still seemed to ignore. I believe it wound up being an issue with caching. I have not tried to re-implement the access in this way. I wound up getting it to work by grouping my certs in the WEB-INF and then adding in an exclude in the pom.xml

<resource>
<directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
<filtering>true</filtering>
<targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
<excludes>
    <exclude>certificates/*.p12</exclude>
</excludes>
</resource>